# stack of arrays usage (argument passing/returning)

Tags: c++

I have to work on several functions that need to have as argument a stack of arrays.

This is the example:

```
using namespace std;

typedef vector<array<array<short,2>,64>> dmat;
typedef stack<array<short,2>> lifo;
typedef array<short,2> array2;

    array2 posible(lifo& pila, int j){   // Gets the stack by reference
                    array2 ret=pila.top();
                    return ret;     
    }
```

The questions are:

- Is this correct? I mean, can I assign and return the element in my stack that way?
- Let's suppose I have declared `dmat sol` and I want to copy the stack  *pila* to the first element in vector sol. Is this correct? `sol[0]=lifo;`
- Is this syntax `pila.top()[1]` legal?

Comment: There is most likely not an implicit conversion between `array<short,2>` (what is in your `lifo`) and `array<int,2>` (your `array2`). So, no, this isn't going to work. But, then, your compiler would have explained that to you if you tried to compile it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this correct? I mean, can I assign and return the element in my stack that way?

Now you've changed the type to match, yes. This will return a copy (not a reference) of the array on top of the stack.

In the original question, no; as I'm sure your compiler would have said. There's no implicit conversion between an array of `short` (which `top()` gives you) and an array of `int` (which you try to assign that to). You can return the same array type by value or reference; or write a little conversion function if you need to change the type for some reason.

> Is this correct? `sol[0]=lifo;`

No; again, the compiler should have told you. You're trying to assign a `stack` to an `array`. Change the type of `dmat` to `vector<lifo>`, and you can copy a `lifo` into it.

> Is this syntax `pila.top()[1]` legal?

Yes, that gives the second element of the array on top of the stack. `top()` returns a reference to that array, which `[1]` can index.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the types' errors are due to copying here parts of the code. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not valid because the types of `array2` and `decltype(pila.top())` are disparate: `array<short,2>` cannot be implicitly converted to an `array<int,2>`. If you change the type of `array2` then your program will be semantically correct.

No, `sol[0] = lifo` is not valid as you are trying to assign a `stack` to an `array`

Yes, `pila.top()[1]` returns the second element of the `array` at the top of the `stack`.